# Unable to use grass GIS algorithms in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am unable to use GRASS GIS algorithms like v.distance in QGIS. Earlier I used to use the same from QGIS before opening standalone GRASS GIS GUI.
Is there anything I need to do to use GRASS algorithms in QGIS.

[image]

Comment: What versions of QGIS and GRASS are involved? Is this a linux system - which distro?

Comment: QGIS version
2.14.17-Essen
GRASS GIS 7.2.1
Ubuntu 16.04